# Observe photons

Tags: visible-light, photons

Could they observe photons of light? Or is it so small for us to see? I think if we would come to know more about photons, and their motion and so its interaction with matter, we would understand more about why the speed of light is constant, and why doesn't it just follow up with our logic..

Comment: Single photons have been observed a long time ago using the photo effect and photographic emulsions. If you want to do it yourself, you can get a used photomultiplier tube on the internet for little money. Unfortunately, one can't learn much from them since their statistics basically follows the intensity predicted by Maxwell's equations.

Comment: That's great, but what do u mean by single photons?  Are there photons attached to other things? Like what

Comment: What do you mean by "observe"?   What kind of observation would satisfy you?  To you mean "see with my eyes"?

Comment: A single photon is simply a quantum of energy and angular momentum of the electromagnetic field. In a photomultiplier tube it makes a small current pulse that can be amplified. Here is what it looks like: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiZCq.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I detect single photons in the lab; I use a commercial system, based on an avalanche photo detection system.

The human eye can is also very sensitive, and if sufficiently dark adapted, can "see" a few photons at a time: see http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Quantum/see_a_photon.html